# How to export Plotly graph into CSV file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plotly, plotly.js

How to export Plotly graph into CSV file ?
I have Plotly graph in jQuery and i want export it in CSV file...I do have option of png but i want to export it in CSV...I have already tried with Plotly docs but it didn't work.